# Standard(s) for data representing measurement times with their interval of validity?

Tags: representation, time

Is there a standard for representing the time interval of a measurement?

Any actual measurement is made at a point in time with, perhaps, an interval over which it is considered valid.  For example, a census datum on a State's population for the year 1990 would be associated with the interval `1990/01/01T00:00:00.0000` duration `1 year`.

Comment: You could assume that the value is correct until the next time step present in the data -- is that what you mean?